# Класс, реализующий несколько COM интерфейсов.

Tags: atl, c++

Появилась следующая проблема: имеется класс(ATL), который должен реализовывать несколько  com-интерфейсов. У каждого из интерфейсов объявлен уникальный [uuid]. Однако при попытке вызова реализаций методов данных интерфейсов получаю ошибку  unable to cast com X object of type to interface type Y.

Подскажите, с чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Либо у Вас в разделе описания этого класса не указан нужный Вам интерфейс в блоке

```
BEGIN_COM_MAP(CYourClass)
COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IYourInterface)
END_COM_MAP()
```

Либо в idl файле ошибка и это интерфейс там не указан:

```
coclass YourClass
{
    interface IYourInterface;
};
```